# When I say require("http://url.com/directory/file.php?test=name") it returns 0 why is this?

Tags: php

When I say require("http://url.com/directory/file.php?test=name") it returns 0 why is this? I also cannot call values ($value) with PHP. How can I do this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please edit the question title and/or the question: they're not correlating at the moment!

Comment: -1 Seeing a trend of half-baked questions from this user.

Comment: Stack Overflow won't debug your website for you. You'd be better off going here first: http://www.w3schools.com/ and make sure you learn about best practices, then validate it at http://validator.w3.org/ for general checks and http://browsershots.org/ for cross-browser previews. If after that there are still issues you can't resolve, then post on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn up error reporting
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get the specific error message. If it is something like:

```
Warning: require() [function.require]: 

http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0
```

then you know that it is a security setting in `php.ini`

Although, I would imagine that you are actually retrieving the file, but its contents are `'0'`. I am guessing this because `require` will output `1` on success and throw a fatal error otherwise.

And as far as I know there is no `values` function in PHP.

Comment: When I added the following line to the script:  error_reporting(E_ALL); nothing happened. What???

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration you may not be able to include sources outside your host machine because it is a security vulnerability.  It would be better to use curl to get the content from the secondary source.